# Please help me prove following inequality

Tags: inequality

$(1+x)^{\theta}(1+y)^{1-\theta}-x^{\theta}y^{1-\theta}\geq1$ where $x,y\geq 0$ and $\theta\in(0,1).$

Comment: I want transform it into $e^{\theta n(1+x)+(1-\theta)ln(1+y)} \geq e^{1+ln(1+x^{\theta}y^{\theta})}$

Answer (score 0):

$(1+x)^{\theta}=1+P(x, \theta)+x^{\theta}$

$(1+y)^{1-\theta}=1+Q[y, (1-\theta)]+y^{1-\theta}$

$A=(1+x)^{\theta}(1+y)^{1-\theta}=1+M(P(x, \theta)Q[y, (1-\theta)])+x^{\theta}y^{1-\theta}-x^{\theta}y^{1-\theta}$

$A=(1+x)^{\theta}(1+y)^{1-\theta}=1+M(P(x, \theta)Q[y, (1-\theta)])>1$

where P, Q and M represent polynomials.Equality is when $\theta=0$

Answer (score 0):

Given function,
$$f(x)=(1+x)^\theta(1+y)^{1-\theta}-x^\theta y^{1-\theta}$$

let's find when the derivative is zero:
$$
\frac{d f}{d x} = \theta\left(\frac{1+y}{1+x}\right)^{1-\theta}-\theta\left(\frac yx\right)^{1-\theta} = 0,\\
\frac{1+y}{1+x} =\frac yx,\qquad x=y.
$$

Thus $f(x)$ has only one minimum when $x=y$ (you can check that this is minimum by letting $x=0$). The value of the function in the point of minimum:
$$
\min f(x) = f(y) = (1+y)^{\theta+1-\theta} - y^{\theta+1-\theta} = (1+y)-y=1
$$